# Rescale one list of matrices to another

Tags: r, list, rescale

I have two lists of 2-columns matrices like these:

```
> stck.list
[[1]]
             [,1]         [,2]
[1,]  0.000000000  0.000000000
[2,]  0.001082767 -0.008137698
[3,] -0.005346008  0.013462373
[4,]  0.012179531  0.046037670
[5,]  0.035469135  0.033196833

[[2]]
             [,1]         [,2]
[1,]  0.000000000 0.0000000000
[2,]  0.004100097 0.0001743182
[3,]  0.001005368 0.0008254498
[4,]  0.011574428 0.0077799754
[5,] -0.006285223 0.0063603749

> stck.list.2
[[1]]
            [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 0.000000000  0.000000000
[2,] 0.003678552  0.009008164
[3,] 0.007416574  0.003603477
[4,] 0.005194380 -0.004445452
[5,] 0.002181469 -0.005857811

[[2]]
              [,1]          [,2]
[1,]  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
[2,]  0.0020240535 -0.0011925407
[3,] -0.0003965362  0.0013492189
[4,]  0.0053106932  0.0001212016
[5,]  0.0023810324  0.0054779249
```

And i need to rescale values from first column from first matrix from first list to first column from first matrix from second list, e.t.c.
Manually i can do it for each column separately for one matrix like that:

```
sc_x.1 <- scales::rescale(stck.list[[1]][,1], to = range(stck.list.2[[1]][,1]))
sc_y.1 <- scales::rescale(stck.list[[1]][,2], to = range(stck.list.2[[1]][,2]))
```

Is it real to do it?
So  the main goal is to dotplot each corresponding matrices from two lists on corresponding axes. Maybe there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Map

```
Map(function(x, y) scales::rescale(x, to = range(y)) , stck.list, stck.list.2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i need.